# Windows 2008 R2 Memory Management

Tags: memory

How does Windows manage physical and virtual memory?  As I understand it, once the system fully utilizes physical memory, it will engage virtual memory.  How is virtual memory managed? If physical memory becomes available, will it move from virtual to physical? or remain in virtual until the process or application ends?

So in theory, if application Z starts and physical memory if fully utilized, it will use virtual memory.  Will application Z ever move to physical memory? or will it remain in virtual memory space until it closes or ends?

Thank You!

Comment: Does this question result from a specific problem you're having, or is it just general interest? The reason I ask is because you would do better to post your original problem if so. Windows memory management algorithms are more complex than simply using the pagefile if physical memory is exhausted. Even when physical memory is available, pages are written out to the page file for a variety of reasons. Best not to mess with it unless you have a very specific problem and you really know what you're doing.

Comment: We have some systems where we see physical memory utilization around 50% and virtual memory utilization above 80%.  Have a better understanding of how this works in general would be helpful down the line.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, "virtual memory" is actually an abstraction which includes physical memory and the page file. Your application is always using virtual memory and sees it as one big contiguous block of memory. The OS then decides where to actually store the data at any given moment. What I think you're referring to as virtual memory is actually the page file or swap file, which is stored on disk.

Comment: Are the machines in question actually experiencing any issues that caused you to look at the memory usage? If not, then I would just leave it. If ain't broke, don't fix it. EDIT: If they are experiencing issues, post that as a question - you could well be looking in the wrong place for the problem, but we can't help if we don't know the original issue.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the page files, but that actually raises another question.  If an SNMP monitor is showing 90% virtual memory, this is actually a combination of both physical and page file so from that counter you can't abstract how much of the page file is really in use?

Comment: This was a question posed to us from our applications team who noticed this from our monitoring system.  I am not aware of any issues regarding these systems, but if there are, I will research and post a better question.  Sorry for the ambiguity of the question.

Comment: There should be an SMTP monitor you can tap for page file usage specifically. When you post another question, I would explain a little more about what applications are running on the servers. Memory usage patterns vary widely depending on the workload, so it would help. High memory usage isn't necessarily a bad thing if you don't have perf problems. Apps like SQL and Exchange will try and load as much of a db into memory as it can to improve access time. Free memory is a waste!

Comment: Newt - Thanks for clearing up the details. I am aware of SQL and Exchange's behavior but wanted to have a better understanding of how memory was managed.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is arguably off-topic, but there is at least one good answer:

Get the [Windows Internals book(s) from MS Press](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) and read them, specifically Chapter 10 (6th Edition)  These are probably the best overall guide to how Windows works (and the chapter on memory management is quite detailed).